# Assign certain number of values to cells

Tags: r, random

I created a data frame with 20 observations, an extra column with all NAs. I'm wondering if there's a way to randomly assign for example 15 "YES" and 10 "NO" or randomly assign for example 15 "1" and 10 "0" for column "A". I would appreciate all the help there is. Thanks in advance!

```
dt <- data.frame(ID <- 1:20)
dt <- dt %>% 
  add_column(A = NA)%>%
  rename(ID = ID....1.20)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is `sample`, which will select at random elements of a vector (with its default `replace=FALSE` argument). I'd suggest you use `tibble` which has many advantages over a `data.frame`.

```
#If you want the reproducible results, use set.seed
set.seed(1)

#create a vector with the desired answers
yesnovector<-c(rep("Yes",15), rep("No", 10))

#create tibble and add randomly selected elements from the yes/no vector
tibble(ID=1:length(yesnovector))%>%
add_column(A=sample(yesnovector))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I'm more interested in sampling certain number of "Yes"s and "No"s instead of just sampling random number of "Yes"s and "No"s. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I've just modified the answer according to your comment.